# How to fix 'Random number' when i "buy item"

Tags: php

I am trying to create a code to generate a number between 1 and 100 and when buy he don't reponse

```
case 'rep':
$min=1;
  $max=20;
  $number = mt_rand($min, $max);
  $rep2 = Config::getData('pp_reputation_points','core_members','name',$_SESSION['user']) ;

  if( $rep2 <= 500 ) {
        $q = Config::$g_con->prepare( 'UPDATE `core_members` SET `pp_reputation_points` = `pp_reputation_points` + ? WHERE `member_id` = ?  ' );
        $q->execute(mt_rand($min, $max),array($name_to_id));
          echo Config::error($lang['ERROR_SUCCESS'],'success');
} else {

          echo Config::error($lang['ERROR_REP'],'danger');
          die();
}
```